# Xcode 4: "No Filter Results" when attempting to add a target dependency

Tags: xcode4

I'm attempting to figure out how to use Libraries in Xcode following [this tutorial](http://pymatics.com/2011/12/23/tutorial-develop-a-private-framework-for-your-mac-app-using-xcode-4s-workspace-feature/). Everything seems straightforward up to the point of adding the target dependencies. Whenever I click "+" to add a target dependency in "Build Phases", my project briefly flashes into view then disappears behind a view that says "No Filter Results".

There are no white spaces in my project directory tree all the way back to root. I'm using Xcode 4.6.1. I've tried typing my project name in the search pane and adding the files to my project a bunch of different ways, all with the same results. Is this a known bit of weirdness in Xcode or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually figured this out on my own. The solution, when Xcode gets into this state, is to close it and restart and adding target dependencies works as expected.

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug in Xcode v4.6.3 for me too. If you drag a subproject into the main project and change the Location in the File Inspector of the subproject from "Absolute Path" to "Relative to Project" or "Relative to Group" then adding the subproject as under "Target Dependencies" under the main project becomes impossible because the project is filtered from view.

I can confirm that the only solution that works reliably for me as well is to quit and restart Xcode after this state occurs and it self corrects.

Comment: phew... I was over thinking and trying to find why these two projects are not compatible with each other? Xcode restart solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This question is a bit old, but I just stumbled on the same problem. Xcode's navigator was displaying "*No filter results*" instead of the project structure. I closed Xcode and re-opened and this did not solve the problem.

What solved was to go to *Navigate > Reveal in Project Navigator*. After this, the structure appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem remains at Xcode 11.1 .

I used another approach, I've been deleting my source project .xcworkspace, after that is just use the pod commands: pod deintegrate and pod install; Open your "new .xcworkspace". It's done !

You don't need commit any new thing that will show up on git status (.project or whatever), discard if you wish and lets code!